# Check all radio buttons by dividing tab contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, select, radio-button

I have select option tags.
And there are 4 radio buttons in each tab contents.
They need to be checked. but It is checked only when the first option is selected content page.

```
<div class="user_select mb30">
<select class="form-control input-sm multiple h40" name="user_select">
    <option value="select1">講演者1</option>
　　　　<option value="select2">講演者2</option>
    <option value="select3">講演者3</option>
　　　　<option value="select4">講演者4</option>
    <option value="select5">講演者5</option>
    <option value="select6">講演者6</option>
    <option value="select7">講演者7</option>
    <option value="select8">講演者8</option>
    <option value="select9">講演者9</option>
    <option value="select10">講演者10</option>
</select>
```

```
<input type="radio" value="radio1" name="file01"><label>配布する</label>
<input type="radio" value="radio2" name="file02"><label>配布しない</label>

<input type="radio" value="radio03" name="file03"><label for="radio03">公開する</label>
<input type="radio" value="radio04" name="file04"><label for="radio04">公開しない</label>

$(document).ready(function() {
var counter = 0 -1;
$('[name=user_select]').children('option').each(function(){
    counter++;
});
for (var i = 1 ; i <= counter ; i++) {
    $('.tab-pane:first').clone().attr('id','select' + (i+1)).appendTo('.tabContent');
}
$('.tab-pane').hide();
$('.tab-pane:first-child').show();

$('[name=user_select]').change(function() {
    var userNama = $('[name=user_select]').val();
    var idName = '#'+userNama
    $('.tab-pane').hide();
    $(idName).fadeIn(400);
});
```

I don't know following source I tried.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var select_num = $('option[value!=""]').val().length;
var z = select_num * $('input[type=radio]').length;
for (var x = 1 ; x <= z ; x++) {
            $('.tab-pane input[type=radio]').each(function(x){
               // $(this).attr('type','radio');
               // $(this).attr('id','radio' + (x+1));
                $(this).attr($('label[for='+ $(this).attr('id','radio' + (x+1)) +']'));
            });
           // $('.tab-pane label').each(function(y){
             //   $(this).attr('for','radio' + (y+1));
           // });
    }
     });
```

Comment: Can you provide code of the tabs you're talking about?

Comment: "*They need to be checked*" - when? Why? Based on what event or interaction?

Answer (score 0):

You can attach data-parametr to your radios:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[name=user_select]').change(function() {
    var userNama = $(this).val();
    var idName = '#' + userNama;
    $('.tab-pane').hide();
    $('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', false);

    $(idName).fadeIn(400);
    $('input[data-tab="' + userNama + '"]').prop('checked', true);
  });
});
```

```css
.tab-pane {
  display:none;
}
#select1 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control input-sm multiple h40" name="user_select">
  <option value="select1">講演者1</option> 
  <option value="select2">講演者2</option>
  <option value="select3">講演者3</option>
</select>
<div class="tab-pane" id="select1">
  <h2>Tab 1</h2>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="select2">
  <h2>Tab 2</h2>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="select3">
  <h2>Tab 3</h2>
</div>

<h2>Radios</h2>
<div>
  <input type="radio" data-tab="select1" value="radio1" name="file01" checked>
  <label for="radio01">file01</label>
  <input type="radio" data-tab="select1" value="radio2" name="file02" checked>
  <label for="radio02">file02</label>
  <input type="radio" data-tab="select1" value="radio3" name="file03" checked>
  <label for="radio03">file03</label>
  <input type="radio" data-tab="select1" value="radio4" name="file04" checked>
  <label for="radio04">file04</label>

</div>
<div>
  <input type="radio" data-tab="select2" value="radio1" name="file05">
  <label for="radio05">file05</label>
  <input type="radio" data-tab="select2" value="radio2" name="file06">
  <label for="radio06">file06</label>
  <input type="radio" data-tab="select2" value="radio3" name="file07">
  <label for="radio07">file07</label>
  <input type="radio" data-tab="select2" value="radio4" name="file08">
  <label for="radio08">file08</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="radio" data-tab="select3" value="radio1" name="file09">
  <label for="radio09">file09</label>
  <input type="radio" data-tab="select3" value="radio2" name="file10">
  <label for="radio10">file10</label>
  <input type="radio" data-tab="select3" value="radio3" name="file11">
  <label for="radio11">file11</label>
  <input type="radio" data-tab="select3" value="radio4" name="file12">
  <label for="radio12">file12</label>
</div>
```